# Unable to create text index in java reactive streams mongodb driver

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut, reactive-streams

I am trying to apply text indexing in description and name field. I am unable to create the index using the following method. Can somebody help to find the issue with the following piece of code.

```
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.*;

private MongoCollection<Obj> getObjCollection() {
            MongoCollection<Obj> objList= mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName).getCollection(objCollection, Obj.class);
            objList.createIndex(Indexes.compoundIndex(Indexes.text("Description"),Indexes.text("Name")));
            return objList;
            
     }
```

Comment: See example code at: [Reactive Streams Java Driver - Admin Quick Tour - Create An Index](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/1.13/getting-started/quick-tour-admin/).